# How to install the object 'create' when I want to create my own package?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

I would like to create my own package, so I did : `New Project/New Directory/R package using devtools`
Then I put `mypackage` in Directory Name and choose the folder, but when I click on `Create Project`, I got the error message :

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'create' not found
```

I think I have all the required packages installed (`devtools v. 2.1.0, roxygen2 v.6.1.1, usethis v.1.5.1, ...)`
I use `R` version : `3.6.0` and `RStudio` version : `1.1.442` (the problem is the same with `v.1.2.1335`)

Edit : 
It works by following `New Project -> New Directory -> R Package` instead of `devtools`, but I would like to use `devtools` and understand where my problem comes from

But I didn't find how to resolve my problem... I am open to any help :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using RStudio 1.2.1335. Can you update RStudio?

Comment: Yes thank you ! I did it, but I still have the same problem and I don't understand why

Comment: Is this the full error message? Which OS are you on? Anything unusual about the path where you want to create the package, like space in the path name? Have you tried `New Project -> New Directory -> R Package` instead of `R Package with  devtools`?

Comment: Yes, this is the full message error. A windows opens with the message "R code execution error" and in the console, I get the message written in the above section.
I work with Windows 10 professional and I tried several paths, so I don't think this is the problem.
But when I try `New Project -> New Directory -> R Package` it works. Does that mean that the problem comes from `devtools` ?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be an issue with devtools v2.1.0. I had used v2.0.1, which does not exhibit this problem. I will open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: c.f. https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2097

Comment: I installed `devtools v2.0.1` and I works ! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is specific to devtools version 2.1.0. Downgrading to version 2.0.1 or upgrading to the current development version fixes the issue. References:

- https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2097
- https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/commit/bf02cdaf86f0f8503745ef029a973233f9be7cff